# Whats the real function of acute operator in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I came across a code:

```
>>> string ="123"
>>> for i in range(4,6):
       string +=`i`


>>> print string
```

The snippet yeilds the following output :

```
12345
```

Its quite obvious that the string literal "123" is getting concatenated with the value of i at every iteration of the loop.
What is the exact use of the acute operator  ` ` ? Are they any other uses of the operator ` `? Shouldn't I be using : `string += str(i)`.? Any perfomance differences if I use `str += str(i)`?

Comment: @DSM any significant performance differences between them ? any references to the operator in appreciated ?

Comment: It's a deprecated alias for `repr`, so it shouldn't be used anymore anyway.

Comment: @MaximeLorant ..is this operator only for python or has it uses in languages like c and java ? correct me if i am wrong....

Comment: Never seen that elsewhere, but I don't know everything about every languages, I might be wrong :-'